# check owner permissions from file (multiple paths results) in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, permissions

friends,
I have a problem with my script. I tried to find a full path of /bin/openssl and next save results to the file and read from the file paths and check permissions and owners. 
But in the result file /tmp/lista.txt , I have multiple paths. How to make a script to read and check every path from file result.
Any ideas?

```
#!/bin/sh


module_id="AV.1.8.2.1"
echo " === $module_id module === "

#MODULE BODY
find / -wholename "*bin/openssl" -print > /tmp/list.txt

file="/tmp/list.txt"
path=$(cat /tmp/list.txt)
os=$(uname)
permission_other_good=0



if [ -e $path ]
then
    if [ $os = "Linux" ]
    then
        gid_min=$(grep ^GID_MIN /etc/login.defs)
        gid_min_value=$(echo $gid_min | cut -d " " -f2)
        uid_min=$(grep ^UID_MIN /etc/login.defs)
        uid_min_value=$(echo $uid_min | cut -d " " -f2)
        sys_gid_max=$(grep ^SYS_GID_MAX /etc/login.defs)
        sys_gid_max_value=$(echo $sys_gid_max | cut -d " " -f2)
        sys_uid_max=$(grep ^SYS_UID_MAX /etc/login.defs)
        sys_uid_max_value=$(echo $sys_uid_max | cut -d " " -f2)
        user_uid=$(stat -c %u $path)
        user=$(stat -c %U $path)
        group_gid=$(stat -c %g $path)
        group=$(stat -c %G $path)
        permission_other=$(stat -c %A $path | cut -b 8-10)

        if [ -z $gid_min_value ]
        then
            gid_min_value=1000
        fi

        if [ -z $uid_min_value ]
        then
            uid_min_value=1000
        fi

        if [ -z $sys_gid_max_value ]
        then
            sys_gid_max_value=$((gid_min_value-1))
        fi 

        if [ -z $sys_uid_max_value ]
        then
            sys_uid_max_value=$((uid_min_value-1))
        fi
    fi        

    if [ $os = "AIX" ]
    then
        gid_min_value=$(cat /etc/security/.ids | cut -d " " -f4)
        sys_gid_max_value=$((gid_min_value-1))
        uid_min_value=$(cat /etc/security/.ids | cut -d " " -f2)
        sys_uid_max_value=$((uid_min_value-1))
        user_uid=$(istat $path | awk -F " " 'NR==3{print $2}' | cut -d "(" -f1)
        user=$(istat $path | awk -F " " 'NR==3{print $2}' | cut -d "(" -f2 | cut -d ")" -f1)
        group_gid=$(istat $path | awk -F " " 'NR==3{print $4}' | cut -d "(" -f1)
        group=$(istat $path | awk -F " " 'NR==3{print $4}' | cut -d "(" -f2 | cut -d ")" -f1)
        permission_other=$(istat $path | awk -F " " 'NR==2{print $2}' | cut -b 7-9)
    fi    

    if [ $permission_other = "r-x" ] || [ $permission_other = "r--" ] || [ $permission_other = "--x" ] || [ $permission_other = "---" ]
    then
        permission_other_good=1  
    fi

    if [ $user_uid -le $sys_uid_max_value ] && [ $group_gid -le $sys_gid_max_value ] && [ $permission_other_good -eq 1 ]
    then
        compliant="Yes"
        actual_value="user = $user group = $group permission = $permission_other"
    else
        compliant="No"
        actual_value="user = $user group = $group permission = $permission_other"
    fi
else
    compliant="N/A"
    actual_value="File $file does not exist"
fi

# SCRIPT RESULT

echo :::$module_id:::$compliant:::$actual_value:::
echo " === End of $module_id module === "
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using bash, I would advise against using temporary files because it has a lot of caveats due to the filesystem (what happens if your disk is full? what happens if the file exists? what happens if you don’t have write permissions over the base directory? etc.) and due to the limitations of storing filenames in line-based text files (though this should not be an issue for finding `openssl`).

If you want to parse a list of files, here is a common and safe way to do that:

```sh
find / -wholename "*bin/openssl" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' path
do
  # Write your code here using the 'path' variable
done
```

But because you are storing variables *inside* the for loop, they would be limited to the scope of the loop because of the pipe operation between `find` and `while`. You can circumvent this problem by using process substitution instead:

```sh
while IFS= read -r -d '' path
do
  # Write your code here using the 'path' variable
done < <(find / -wholename "*bin/openssl" -print0)
```

This behaves essentially the same as the previous code, except that the variable scope is not limited to the loop.

PS. You will have to deal with the assignment of your variables over several openssl paths. If you just copy/paste your code inside the for loop, the value of `compliant` and `actual_value` will retain information for the last path in the loop, which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is how in bash you read a file line by line

```
#!/bin/bash
inputfile="/tmp/list.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
  echo "do your stuff with $line"
done < "$inputfile"
```

Answer (score 0):

okey the best solution is to put the result in an array and then for

```
declare -a my_paths

my_paths=($(find / -wholename "*bin/openssl" -print 2>/dev/null))

for my_path in "${my_paths[@]}"; do

done
```